# How to find out what podcidr is assigned to each node by calico CNI in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, calico, cni

Is there any direct command to fetch the podcidr assigned to each node when using calico CNI.

I am looking for exact network and netmask assigned to each node. I am not able to fetch it from `kubectl get nodes` neither via `podCIDR value` nor via `projectcalico.org/IPv4VXLANTunnelAddr` annotation. Also looks like the annotation will also differ based on VXLAN or IPIP tunnel used by calico.

Tried to fetch via podCIDR key from nodes. Got the following output. Which wasn't the network assigned to the nodes.

```
kubectl get nodes -oyaml | grep -i podcidr -B 1
  spec:
    podCIDR: 192.168.0.0/24
    podCIDRs:
--
  spec:
    podCIDR: 192.168.2.0/24
    podCIDRs:
```

Tried to fetch it via calico annotation. Was able to find the network but the netmask was missing.

```
kubectl get nodes -oyaml | grep -i ipv4vxlan
      projectcalico.org/IPv4VXLANTunnelAddr: 192.168.33.64
      projectcalico.org/IPv4VXLANTunnelAddr: 192.168.253.192
```

Tried to fetch it via calico pod. Found the exact network and netmask i.e **192.168.33.64/26** from the calico log.

```
kubectl logs calico-node-h2s9w   -n calico-system | grep cidr
2020-12-14 06:54:50.783 [INFO][18] tunnel-ip-allocator/ipam.go 140:
Attempting to load block cidr=192.168.33.64/26 host="calico-master"
```

But i want to avoid looking at logs of calico pod on each node.
Is there a better way to find the podcidr assigned to each node via a single command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like calico adds a [custom resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/) called ipamblocks and it contains the podcidr assigned to each cluster node.

The name of the custom resource itself contains the node's podcidr.

```
kubectl get ipamblocks.crd.projectcalico.org 
NAME               AGE
10-42-123-0-26     89d
10-42-187-192-26   89d
```

Command to fetch the exact podcidr and nodeip:

```
kubectl get ipamblocks.crd.projectcalico.org -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{'podNetwork: '}{.spec.cidr}{'\t NodeIP: '}{.spec.affinity}{'\n'}"
```

```
podNetwork: 10.42.123.0/26   NodeIP: host:<node1-ip>
podNetwork: 10.42.187.192/26     NodeIP: host:<node2-ip>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `etcdctl` to know details of subnet block assigned to each node.

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl ls /calico/ipam/v2/host/node1/ipv4/block/
```

Above example for a node `node1` will give something like below as output.

```
/calico/ipam/v2/host/node1/ipv4/block/192.168.228.192-26
```

Comment: Thanks . But i get the following from that  calico command line.                             
 ```calicoctl get ippools                                                                                                   
 NAME                  CIDR             SELECTOR                                                               
 default-ipv4-ippool   192.168.0.0/16   all() ```                                                                         
 I dont get the cidr assigned to each node of the cluster.

Comment: thanks. can this also be fetched via any api call to kube-apiserver?

Comment: Don't think it's possible according to my knowledge

Comment: Thanks! The thing is that a worker entry under the /calico/ipam/v2/host is missing. This results in that worker getting the same block IP CIDR with the master, causing lots of conflicts due to blackhole created etc. Why this could happen? Where to check for any clues?